# Handlebars wont show object property of a JSON.Stringfy object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

Good Afternoon everyone im rendering my object

```
router.get('/profile', authController.isLoggedIn,  (req,res) => {
    if ( req.user ) {
        res.render('profile', {
            user: JSON.stringify(req.user)
        })
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
})
```

What I want is to show my username in my HTML. If I use just user it shows everything, but I cannot access the property. Also, I'm creating a variable of current_user to use it in local javascript.
If I don't stringify my user from above it works but then I can not use the variable

```
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{user.username}} welcome back</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Example test test test dont know whats going on help me hello!!!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        Node MySQL - Project
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>var current_user = {{{user}}} </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use JSON.parse(user)

Comment: @NikitaAplin in place of JSON.stringify(req.user) right?
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: show me your code, when you fetch data please

Comment: @NikitaAplin This is my current user when I console log it in my local script [link](https://i.imgur.com/zwdlbT6.png). This is my HTML when I use {{user.email}} etc
[link](https://i.imgur.com/2TVnDaf.png) . Nothing shows up.

Comment: You are trying to do two things with `user`. First is to use it as an object for your template to pull values from; the second is to use it as JSON so that it can render as JavaScript on the client-side and get assigned to a local variable. I would suggest using two separate variables - the JSON stringified and the regular; or creating a helper that can be called from the template and that will do the JSON.stringifying.